# Why does latex think it's tomorrow already?

Tags: pdftex, datetime, article

Strange problem here:

```
Brandon@forge ~/Dropbox/research.local/oil
$ date
Tue, Nov 27, 2012  6:14:23 PM

Brandon@forge ~/Dropbox/research.local/oil
$ cat <<EOF | pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
EOF
```

gives me a document whose content reads "November 28, 2012".
Now, I imagine this has something to do with locale or time zone – but why would that be different inside of TeX than at the command line?

Worth mentioning: I'm running Cygwin on Windows 7 and TeX Live 2012.

Comment: What does `\currenttime` from the [`datetime`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datetime) package give you?

Comment: I'm running the same system (Cygwin, Windows 7, TeX Live 2012) and the output is as expected. You're sure you checked `texput.pdf`?

Comment: I'm not good at these things but it's not possible to have Dropbox server time, is that right?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel-- aha! it says it's 8 hours ahead, which I think is GMT.  So it sounds like maybe I don't have a locale variable set.. but unfortunately, I don't see any discussion about time zones in the datetime documentation

Comment: @percusse, I think the current directory is incidental- the result is the same from my home directory.

Comment: `datetime` picks up the date and time from the TeX count registers `\year`, `\month`, `\day` and `\time`. TeX sets these at the start of the tex/latex run. I assume it gets the information from the operating system it's running on. What do get if you use `\pdfcreationdate` ?

Comment: Just built a document now and got: D:20121207010418Z.  That's 0104, right?  Local time is 17:04 on December 6.  Conclusion: my OS is not reporting the correct time zone to tex.  solution: ?????

Comment: What happens if you execute the windows versions of the `date` and `time` commands, eg from `cmd` instead of from `bash`? And I assume you're using the `cygwin`-packaged version of `texlive`?

Comment: @cyberSingularity, they are consistent.  Both report the locale-current time (of 13:44).  No, I did not use cygwin to install TeX Live because I remain somewhat mistrustful of cygwin.  I installed using the installer from texlive.org

Comment: Any other applications displaying the same/similar issue? Any unusual environment variables set (such as `TZ`)? Any unusual locale/time zone settings in control panel? Are you able to invoke any Windows APIs for time etc, if so, what do they report?

Comment: Here's my env: http://pastebin.com/frpSu94v ; TZ is not set in windows ; in bash it's "America/Los_Angeles"

Comment: Sorry, haven't asked you yet: what if you run `pdflatex` from `cmd` instead of through `bash`? Or unset `TZ` in `bash` and run from `bash`?

Comment: Remember that if you launch `cmd` from `bash`, it inherits some of the `bash` environment, so you should launch it separately (both for the `pdflatex` tests and for reporting your environment).

Comment: Unsetting TZ does the trick.  if you post it as an answer, I guess that means you win the bounty.  Any idea what the proper setting is for US west coast? It looks to me like "America/Los_Angeles" is supposed to be correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As soon as you mentioned the `TZ` environment variable, it seemed like the likely culprit, especially as you are running the Windows version of TeX Live rather than the cygwin version (which is a perfectly reasonable thing to do, so hopefully this is the only issue it causes). I believe Windows and cygwin have different interpretations of that variable, and when running Windows binaries from cygwin sessions, the cygwin environment is inherited. Presumably outside of cygwin on your system, the `TZ` variable is not set.

So, to ensure the time is correctly interpreted, you need to unset the `TZ` variable before using native Windows binaries such as the TeX Live binaries. To avoid globally unsetting the variable (which surely serves other needed purposes in cygwin), perhaps consider the use of `bash` aliases, eg `alias pdflatex="TZ= pdflatex"`.

---

To attempt to answer your latter question from the comment about which TZ value to use in `cygwin`, the [official time zone database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) has the following text before the `America/Los Angeles` entry:

```
# US Pacific time, represented by Los Angeles
#
# California, northern Idaho (Benewah, Bonner, Boundary, Clearwater,
# Idaho, Kootenai, Latah, Lewis, Nez Perce, and Shoshone counties,
# and the northern three-quarters of Idaho county),
# most of Nevada, most of Oregon, and Washington
```

Comment: Thanks for the discussion and the solution.  I added an 'unset TZ' into my workflow.